# Issue using mysql variable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the following code to search through a table.
If I don't use the variable it all works fine, as soon as I use the variable (and the field contains special chars) I hit issues like nothing found or the query never finishes.

I have tried a few different things like quotes etc but nothing I have tried works, I need to make sure this works no matter what chars are in the field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
SET @description = 'some string to look for';

SELECT * FROM `tbl_master`
WHERE `description` = @description
AND `id` > (
    SELECT max(`id`)
    FROM `tbl_master`
    WHERE `description` != @description
    AND `id` < (
        SELECT max(`id`)
        FROM `tbl_master`
        WHERE `description` = @description
    )
)
ORDER BY peak DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Example without variable, this works okay but I need to be able to pass a variable to the code.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_master`
WHERE `description` = 'some string to look for'
AND `id` > (
    SELECT max(`id`)
    FROM `tbl_master`
    WHERE `description` != 'some string to look for'
    AND `id` < (
        SELECT max(`id`)
        FROM `tbl_master`
        WHERE `description` = 'some string to look for'
    )
)
ORDER BY peak DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is there a server-side to your application? Or if you are trying this purely in MySQL, is this a part of Stored Procedure or Function? Or is it just a raw query?

Comment: Just a raw query at the moment, I may create a storedproc later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT @description := 'some string to look for', * FROM `tbl_master`
WHERE `description` = @description
AND `id` > (
    SELECT max(`id`)
    FROM `tbl_master`
    WHERE `description` != @description
    AND `id` < (
        SELECT max(`id`)
        FROM `tbl_master`
        WHERE `description` = @description
    )
)
ORDER BY peak DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Just tried this but got an error :(
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `tbl_master`
    WHERE `description` = @description
    AND `id` > (
    SELEC' at line 1